# mysql_fetch_array() value does not display

Tags: php, database

```
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $adminuser = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    // Connecting to database
    include "../StorageScript/connecttomysql.php";
    //sql query
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$adminuser' AND password= '$password' LIMIT 1");

    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }

    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['adminuser'] = $adminuser;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
}
```

In the above code am trying to fetch the user id from the database and place it into a session variable. When i try to echo the $_SESSION['id'] in a different page it does not display any thing. But When i try to echo the username it work.

Comment: SQL Injection warning!

Comment: Have you confirmed, that your SQL returns the correct value?

Comment: Use `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: I suspect logging in with the user name `' OR 1 OR '' = '` may prove interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this command `mysql_fetch_array($sql)` use `$row[0]`.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id = $row[0];
}
```

Or if you want to use `$row["id"]` then use `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
}
```

Of course you should be using mysqli_* or PDO rather than the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

You want only one row from the query..
So don't use while loop....

```
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
$adminuser = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

// Connecting to database
include "../StorageScript/connecttomysql.php";
//sql query
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$adminuser' AND password= '$password' LIMIT 1");

$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$id = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['adminuser'] = $adminuser;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

}